# How can I extract a specific field from a set of nodes?

Tags: entities

I am using Drupal 7.

I have a custom content type with multiple fields. For example, one field contains a thumbnail image. Another is a text field.

There are 36 nodes that use this custom content type. In database terms, I have 36 records.

How do I have Drupal extract a specific field from each of the 36 'records' and display them on a single page?

For example, in PHP I could write an SQL query such as "`select fieldname from table`" and display using `while() { print $row['fieldname']; }.`

How do I achieve this using Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2):

Use views, add fields - only the image - display for that content type only if published. done.

If you want to fine tune it, do some theming.

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to actually do just that. Am I right in thinking 'Views' does a lot of the heavy lifting in Drupal?